# Mount smb share temprorarily with Ansible using module instead of shell

Tags: ansible, centos, smb

I need to mount a smb share to have access on large, shared installation files in Ansible. This works using CLI:

```
- name: Mount share
  become: yes
  shell: "mount.cifs {{ smb_share.path }} {{ smb_share.mount_point }} -o user={{ smb_share.user }},password={{ smb_share.password }},mfsymlinks,exec"
```

However, this has two disadvantages:

- Doesn't follow best practices of using modules instead of shell commands when required
- No detection if already mounted - I'd need to implement this, e.g. by grep for the mountpoint in `mount`

There is a [`mount`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html) module in Ansible. But since this share ist just for installation and uses credentials, I don't want to have it permanently mounted. The `boot` parameter looks what I need, sadly not for Linux:

```
Determines if the filesystem should be mounted on boot.
Only applies to Solaris systems.
```

I still tried to set `boot: no` but as described in the docs, it still creates an `/etc/fstab` entry with the plain text password.

Is there any alternative to have a Windows share temprorarily mounted on CentOS 7 with any Ansible module?

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware there exist some temp mount specific module in ansible.
But from docs you can use *mount* module in the next way:

```
- name: Mount network share
  mount:
    src: //path/to/windows/share
    path: /mnt
    fstype: cifs
    opts: 'username=example@domain,password=Password1!'
    state: mounted
  become: true

- name: Unmount network share
  mount:
    path: /mnt
    state: absent
  become: true
```

First task *state=mounted* will create record in */etc/fstab* and mount that network share, and second task *state=absent* you can use to umount mounted share and remove corresponding record from */etc/fstab*. That is the best option that comes to my mind.